# Align elements with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm on student project ( I have to reproduce desktop mockup) and from many hours I don't know what to do with flexbox. I'm trying to align 3 elements in same rows.

So , I make a division to get the width for each elements and I got 33.33%, but when I'm trying to code it I'm not sure of the reason that the third element go under the two others.

I used the inspector to see

```css
/* GENERAL RULES */

/* FONT */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,300&family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@600&display=swap');

*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body
{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

/* HEADER */

header
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#logo
{
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
#menu ul 
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#menu ul li
{
    padding: 30px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    
}

#menu a:visited
{
    color:black;
}

#menu ul li:hover
{
    border-top: 1px solid #0065FC;
}
#menu ul li a:hover{
    color:#0065FC;
}

/* END OF HEADER */

/* Section-1 */

 .city_search
 {
     margin-left: 35px;
 }

.hosting_description
{
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.hosting_description .city_search > p 
{
    color:gray;
    line-height:45px;
    
}

.hosting_description #map-marker
{
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    padding: 14px 14px 17px 14px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left:4px;
    
}

.hosting_description a 
{
    background-color: #0065FC;
    padding: 14px 14px 13px 14px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top:2px;
    left:53px;
}

.hosting_description a:visited
{
    color:white;
}

.city_search--input{
}
input[type=text]
{
    padding:15px;
    border: none;
    outline: transparent;
    
}
::placeholder
{
    color:black;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.filters
{
    display: flex;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.filters h4{
    margin-left: -8px;
}

.filters .fas
{
    margin-left: -50px;
    background-color:#DEEBFF;
    color: #0065FC;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    left:72px;
    z-index: 1000;
    bottom: 15px;
}


.filters .fas:nth-child(4)
{
    position: relative;
    left: 68px;
}


.filters .fas:nth-child(6)
{
    position: relative;
    left: 68px;
}

.filters p 
{
    margin-left: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding:15px 15px 15px 55px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 15px;
}

.filters .fas:hover
{
color:white;
background-color:#0065FC;
cursor: pointer;
}

.filters p:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    color:white;
background-color:#0065FC;
}

#filters_indications {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color:gray;
}
#filters_indications .fas
 {
    border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
    border-top-right-radius: 80%;
    border-top-left-radius: 80%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 80%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 80%;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:blue;
    margin-right: 8px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 2px;
}

/* END OF SECTION -1 */

/* SECTION -2 */

.section-2
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

.card_hostings{
    
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    background-color: lightgray;
    width:50%; 
    border-radius: 50px / 50px;
    
}



.item{
    position: relative;
    top:100px;
    width:33%;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10%;
    border-top-left-radius:10% ;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10%;
    padding: 5px;
}


.item img{
    width: 100%;
    height:162px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10%;
    border-top-left-radius:10% ;
    
}
.item p {
    line-height: 30px;
}
.card_hostings--2{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 30px;
    
}

.item--2{
    width: 300px;
}

.item--2 img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 162px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10%;
    border-top-left-radius:10% ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Booki - AgenceDevetMoi</title>
    <!-- FAVICON -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./assets/images/logo/Booki@3x.png" />
    <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css"  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <!-- HEADER -->

    <header>
        
        <div id="logo">
            
            <a href="index.html"><img src="./assets/images/logo/Booki.png" height="50" width="100" alt="logo"></a>
            
        </div>
        
        <nav id="menu">
            
            <ul>
                
                <li><a href="#hosting">Hébergements</li></a>
                <li><a href="#activities">Activités</li></a>
                
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        
    </header>
    
    <!-- END OF HEADER -->
    
    <!-- Section-1 -->
    
    <section class="section-1">
        
        <div class="hosting_description">
            
            <div class="city_search">

                <h1>Trouvez votre hébergement pour des vacances de rêve</h1>
                <p>En plein centre ville ou en pleine nature</p>
                <div class="city_search--input">

                    <i id="map-marker" class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Marseille, France"><a href="#">Rechercher</a>

                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="filters">
            
            <h4>Filtres</h4>
                
            
             <i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave"></i>
            <p class="filters_paragraphs">Économique</p>
        
                    
            <i class="fas fa-child"></i>
            <p class="filters_paragraphs">Familial</p>
            
            <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
            <p class="filters_paragraphs">Romantique</p>
            
            <i class="fas fa-dog"></i>
            <p class="filters_paragraphs">Animaux autorisés</p>
            
        </div>
        <p id="filters_indications">
            <i class="fas fa-info"></i>
            
            Plus de 500 logements sont disponibles dans cette ville
        </p>
    </section>
    
    <!-- END OF SECTION-1 -->
    
    <!-- SECTION-2 -->
    
    <section class="section-2">
        
        <h1 id="hosting">Hébergements à Marseille</h1>
        
        <div class="card_hostings">
            
            <!-- FIRST CARD -->
            <div class="item">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/auberge_cannebière.jpg" alt="Auberge La Cannebière">
                <h3 class="card_hostings--title">Auberge La Cannebière</h3>
                <p>Nuit à partir de <strong>25€</strong></p>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <!-- Change the color on light gray-->
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                
            </div>
            <!-- SECOND CARD -->
            <div class="item">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Hôtel_du_port.jpg" alt="Hôtel du port">
                <h3 class="card_hostings--title">Hôtel du port</h3>
                <p>Nuit à partir de 52<strong>€</strong></p>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                
            </div>
            <!-- THIRD CARD -->
            <div class="item">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Hôtel_Les_mouttes.jpg" alt="Hôtel Les mouettes">
                <h3 class="card_hostings--title">Hôtel Les mouettes</h3>
                <p>Nuit à partir de 76<strong>€</strong></p>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <!-- Change the color on light gray-->
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                
            </div>
            <!-- FOURTH CARD -->
            <div class="item">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Hôtel_de_la_mer.jpg" alt="Hôtel de la mer">
                <h3 class="card_hostings--title">Hôtel de la mer</h3>
                <p>Nuit à partir de 46<strong>€</strong></p>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <!-- Change the color on light gray-->
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <!-- Change the color on light gray-->
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                
            </div>
            <!-- FIFTH CARD -->
            <div class="item">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Auberge_Le_Panier.jpg" alt="">
                <h3 class="card_hostings--title">Auberge Le Panier</h3>
                <p>Nuit à partir de <strong>23€</strong></p>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <!-- Change the color on light gray-->
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                
            </div>
            <!-- SIX CARD -->
            <div class="item">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Hôtel_chez_Amina.jpg"  alt="">
                <h3 class="card_hostings--title">Hôtel chez Amina</h3>
                <p>Nuit à partir de 96<strong>€</strong></p>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                
            </div>
            
            
            
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="card_hostings--2">
            <h1>Les plus populaires <i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i></h1>
            
            <div class="item--2">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Hôtel_Le_soleil_du_matin.jpg" alt="Hôtel Le soleil du matin">
                <h3 class="card_hostings--title">Hôtel Le soleil du <br> matin </h3>
                <p>Nuit à partir de 128<strong>€</strong></p>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="item--2">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Au_coeur_de_l'eau_Chambres_d'hôtes.jpg" alt="Au coeur de l'eau Chambres d'hôtes">
                <h3 class="card_hostings--title">Au coeur de l'eau <br> Chambres d'hôtes</h3>
                <p>Nuit à partir de 71<strong>€</strong></p>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <!-- Change the color on light gray-->
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="item--2">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/hebergements/2_large/Hôtel_tout_bleu_tout_blanc.jpg" alt="">
                <h3 class="card_hostings--title">Hôtel Tout bleu et <br> Blanc</h3>
                <p>Nuit à partir de 68<strong>€</strong></p>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <!-- Change the color on light gray-->
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        
    </section>
    
    <!-- END OF SECTION-2 -->
    
    <!-- SECTION-3 -->
    
    
    <section class="section-3">
        
        <h1 id="activities">Activités à Marseille</h1>
        
        <div class="cards_activities">
            
            <div class="elements">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/activites/1_xlarge/Vieux_port.jpg" alt="Vieux port">
                <h3>Vieux port</h3>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="elements">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/activites/1_xlarge/Fort_de_Pomègues.jpg" alt="Fort de Pomègues">
                <h3>Fort de Pomègues</h3>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="elements">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/activites/1_xlarge/Îles_du_Frioul.jpg" alt="Îles du Frioul">
                <h3>Îles du Frioul</h3>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="elements">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/activites/1_xlarge/Parc_National_des_Calanques.jpg" alt="Parc National des Calanques">
                <h3>Parc National des Calanques</h3>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="elements">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/activites/1_xlarge/Parc_National_des_Calanques.jpg" alt="Parc National des Calanques">
                <h3>Parc National des Calanques</h3>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="elements">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/activites/1_xlarge/Notre-Dame-de-la-Garde.jpg" alt="Notre-Dame-de-la-Garde">
                <h3>Notre-Dame-de-la-Garde</h3>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="elements">
                
                <img src="./assets/images/activites/1_xlarge/Parc_Longchamp.jpg" alt="Parc_Longchamp">
                <h3>Parc Longchamp</h3>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </section>
    
    <!-- END OF SECTION-3 -->
    
    <!-- FOOTER -->
    
    <footer>
        
        <h3>À propos</h3>
        
        <ul>
            
            <li>Fonctionnement du site</li>
            <li>Conditions générales de vente</li>
            <li>Données et confidentialité</li>
            
        </ul>
        
        <h3>Nos hébergements</h3>
        
        <ul>
            
            <li>Charte qualité</li>
            <li>Soumettre votre hôtel</li>
            
        </ul>
        
        <h3>Assistance</h3>
        
        <ul>
            
            <li>Centre d'aide</li>
            <li>Nous contacter</li>
            
        </ul>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

what happend and I clearly see that the width seems to be the problem but I don't know how to resolve it...

Could you help me ? ( I already see many topics about flexbox and same problems but I couldn't applies them to my situation)

This is the design that I have to reproduce  and the part that I want to do is the middle one on left with 6 pictures.[image: Mockup/Design]

And here what I've done :
[image: My design]

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproduction? The amount of code is pretty overwhelming. It's also better for isolating the problem. (Maybe remove everything except the flexbox with its items)

Comment: complex stuff like that, grid would be more accurate

Comment: Ok, sorry I'm not used to stackoverflow post ! I'll rewrite it tomorrow 3v3ryb0dy
@callmenikk I can't use grid it is one of the requirement, Flexbox only :( .

Comment: there's to much code and thats reason, reduce your code size and include only that part where you have the problem if is there ability to upload your source code with pictures on any playground for example [repl.it](https://replit.com/) would be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're not factoring in the `padding: 5px`.
So, it's calculating `33% + 5px`, which means each part is MORE than a third, which means only 2 will fit per row.

You either:

1. - remove the 5px padding with width: calc(33% - 10px)
2. - add the rule: border-box: box-sizing so the padding is part of the 33% instead of being added separately

See:

https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css_padding.asp